# unable to connect groovy to oracle

Tags: groovy

I have placed the  ojdbc14.jar in the lib folder and am using the code below to connect to oracle:

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import javax.sql.DataSource
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes

driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    'jdbc:oracle:thin:ratan/rabin123@localhost:1522:orcl');
```

but get the error: `unable to resolve class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes`

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the code on my computer and it worked, so it has to be a classpath issue.

Is port 1522 correct? It's 1521 by default.

Have you tried to create a connection using the `groovy.sql.Sql` class:

```
Sql sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:orcl",
    "ratan", "rabin123", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")
```